# Serializers not working on multiple levels as expected in Django

Tags: python, django, serialization

I have 4 models and 3 serializers.
1 model is a simple through table containing information about which user posted which reaction about which article.

```
models.py

class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=36, default=generate_unique_id, primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True) 
...

class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=36, default=generate_unique_id, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='authored', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
...

class Reaction(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='reacted', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article_id = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='article_details', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sentiment = models.ForeignKey(Sentiment, related_name='sentiment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Sentiment(models.Model):
    like = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    dislike = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
```

```
serializers.py

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    authored = ArticleDetailSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    reacted = ReactedSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',   
            'authored',
            'reacted',
        )
        model = User

class ArticleDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
        )
        model = Article
        
class ReactedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    article_details = ArticleDetailSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'sentiment',
            'article_id',
            'article_details',
        )
        model = Reaction
```

Currently, the output for a GET request for a User shows `authored` correctly.
[image: authored array results]
I copied the logic so `reacted` can be a multi-level object containing `sentiment` and the relevant article information.

I've tried many solutions yet the result for the `User` field `reacted` never includes the `article_details` field.
[image: reacted array results]
I've ensured the `related_name` field in in the `Reacted` model is `article_details` so what am I missing?

I've seen another solution on StackOverflow where someone had multi-level serialization so why is it not working here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`related_name` is useful when you are trying to access reverse relations. For example if you need to acces `Reaction` from `Article` object. But in your case you just want to access article details defined inside `Reaction` model. So you need to use `acticle_id` field name instead of `article_details`:

```
class ReactedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    article_id = ArticleDetailSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'sentiment',
            'article_id',
        )
        model = Reaction
```

UPD: actually `article_details` is not appropriate naming for `related_name` here. Since related name is used when you acces list of related objects from other model, in your case it's `Article`. So it's better ot rename it to `reactions`:

```
article_id = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='reactions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And you can use it like this:

```
article_obj.reactions.all()
```

Comment: I had the relationship backwards in my head. This helped make things clear. Thank you